# Java - Timer class that accepts a time source

Tags: java, timer

I need a replacement of java.util.Timer or java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService that accepts a time source so that it can be driven off of system time **or** some other reference.  I use this timer to periodically execute a method, but need the period to be driven by system time when the application is in "live" mode and some other source when the application is in "playback" mode.

I did see that there are some 3rd party libraries such as guava stopwatch with functionality similar to what I am asking, but I prefer something native to Java due to the policies of the information system I am working on.

I may end up having to write my own, but am asking here since this seems like a need that many would have... Either when working with applications that have alternate concepts of time passage or for testing of units with embedded timers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs it, here is the solution I ended up with.

```
public interface TimeSource {
    long currentTimeMillis();
}

public class AlternateTimeSource implements TimeSource {

    long currentTime = 0;       

    public AlternateTimeSource() {
    }

    public setTime(long time) {
        if (time > currentTime) currentTime = time;
    }

    @Override
    public long currentTimeMillis() {
        return currentTime;
    }
}

public class SystemTimeSource implements TimeSource {

    @Override
    public long currentTimeMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

class SourcedTimerThread extends Thread {

    TimeSource reference_;
    TimerTask task_;
    long period_;
    long executionTime_;
    boolean done = false;

    SourcedTimerThread(TimeSource reference,TimerTask task,long delay,long period) {
        reference_     = reference;
        task_          = task;
        period_        = period >= 0 ? period : 0;
        executionTime_ = reference_.currentTimeMillis() + (delay >= 0 ? delay : 0);
        setName("SourcedTimerThread_"+reference_.getClass().getSimpleName());
        start();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        done = true;
        interrupt();
    }

    public void run() {

        long currentTime;

        while (!done) {
            try {
                currentTime = reference_.currentTimeMillis();
                if (executionTime_>currentTime) { 
                    // Task hasn't yet fired; wait
                    sleep(1);                   }
                else {
                    task_.run();
                    if (period_ > 0) {
                        // Repeating task, reschedule
                        executionTime_ = ((period_ < 0) ? currentTime-period_ : executionTime_ + period_);
                    }
                    else {
                        // Non-repeating task, done
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Build source
TimeSource source = null;
if (alternate) {
    source = new AlternateTimeSource();
}
else {
    source = new SystemTimeSource();
}

// Configure timer
SourcedTimerThread t = new SourcedTimerThread(source,new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    void run() {
        System.out.println("Yay!");
    }
}, delayMs, periodMs);

// Drive timer if necessary
if (alternate) {
    // Drive timer based on alternate source such as data
    source.setTime(dataRecord.getTime());
}

// When ready to cleanup
t.cancel();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` with a custom time source, by doing the following:

Compute the offset or the delta between the custom time source and system time (at initialization), and hold on to the delta in your implementation of `ScheduledExecutorService`. When `schedule` (and similar methods in the interface) are called, use the same offset that you computed at initialization and apply those offsets on the `TimeUnits` being provided. That way - you can rely on the existing implementation of the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think this approach will allow a shift of time, but I may need to handle non-linear passage of time... Example: 1 second of real time passes : 3 seconds of alternate time pass; 1 more second of real time passes : 25 seconds of alternate time pass; etc...